# set default country for current store programatically, magento?

Tags: php, magento

How can i set default country for current store programatically? 
Setting base currency for current store, i can do it by following way:

`Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('USD');`

is there any thing like above to set default country for current store or any other options?

EDIT:

i am using a pop up with allowed countries list (current store) which i fetched by doing the following:

`Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadByStore();`

the user would pick any country and that country should be set to default country for that store. just like i can set current currency using above method.

Comment: (how) did you solve this problem?

Comment: unfortunately not. :-|

Comment: If your goal is to have the tax rate updated depending on the client's country, the way to go is to create a **store** for each destination country: the dropdown appears automatically. Then, create a **store view** for each language of that country.

Comment: @MadMax try my solution it works for me and damm sure it will also works for you, i am using javascript method

Comment: @KeyurShah i'll certainly check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to 
Admin >> Configuration >> General

Set the Default Country over here

Comment: i just edited my question , doing this from configuration is not the priority rather i have to make available (which i did) the list of countries to the user so he may choose one to be set as default (for current session/store, here i am stuck!) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('general/country/default', $countryValueHere, 'stores', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
Mage::getConfig()->reinit();
Mage::app()->reinitStores();
```

Comment: thanks for the response.
it seems that this will change the default setting for country in general, is it not possible to do so for current session only? (keeping the general settings as it is)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a default setup for that purpose. But you can try this extension. It can automatically redirect certain country (or region, or city, or IP)  to certain store.

Rather than asking your users to choose their country, I think this extension can reduce the hassles for doing that. So your users will be happy because they don't need to select their country first from the long dropdown list. And you'll be happy too because those users will be automatically redirected to your selected store.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/country-state-city-ip-to-store-1498.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set config data for particular session using

```
Mage::getConfig()->setNode($path, $value);
```

Where `$path` is path of your configuration in `core_config` table

`$value` is value of your path

***or you can change default country on load page using javascript***